# Why use CONCATENATE vs & in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I noticed that `"EXEC MySproc," & "arg, " & "arg2"` is essentially the same as `=CONCATENATE("EXEC MySproc,", "arg,", "arg2")`   including the ability to use evaluations, functions etecetera.    What is the usecase for using `=CONCATENATE()` vs `&`?

Comment: In the case of a long sequence of string concatenations, CONCATENATE() has the potential to be linear instead of quadratic in the length of the final string. see https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Comment: Anecdotal, but I often use CONCATENATE when joining over three strings, for the sole reason that I am more used to separating arguments with commas than with ampersands... though of course that is not really a valid reason.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I have no idea what your point is. OK, a long sequence of ***independently performed*** string concatenations has the potential to be either linear or quadratic in the length of the final string, depending on how you store the strings in memory. Do you have any evidence (or *any* reason to believe) that `CONCATENATE()` and `&` are *internally implemented* differently in Excel?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's for people who like to type more. Probably the same audience that does things like `=Sum((A1*A2)-A3)` instead of `=(A1*A2)-A3`. (Yes, these people exist, and I don't know why they do that)

It also provides wonderful opportunities to create your very first User Defined Function with VBA to create something more useful than Concatenate().

Excel 2016 (with an Office 365 subscription) has a new function called [TextJoin()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c), which takes a delimiter and a range as arguments and is a lot faster than typing out the ampersands and the delimiters as text strings. Now, THAT is useful.

[image]

Comment: At least SUM can take a range. Thanks for the pointer on TEXTJOIN. Work hasn't upgraded to 2016 yet, but when they do I'll finally be able to retire my UDF.

Comment: Yes, a range input for CONCATENATE would make a useful difference against manual ampersands. Alas, only semicolon works.

Comment: @Konerak semicolon or comma, depending on what your regional settings prefer as the list separator. Semicolon is typically found in European setups, comma in US and other English speaking locations.

Comment: Didn't you mean `=Sum(A1,A2)` (as an alternative to `=A1+B1`)?

Comment: @xehpuk No I didn't. Some people wrap a Sum() function around simple calculations. They could use `=A1+A2` but for some reason, they write `=Sum(A1+A1)`. Or `=Sum(A1-A2)` where they could us `=A1-A2`. Or `=Sum(A1*A2)` where they could use  `=A1*A2`. Some people put all kinds of formulas into a Sum() function and I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: [here is an example](https://superuser.com/q/1216030/241386). I have no idea why one wants to use `CONCATENATE(A1&B1)` or `CONCATENATE(B2)` like that

Comment: They do that because they click the Function button and use the function builder, which will put in all those extra things just because it's how it does things.  They're actually not using the keyboard to type anything.  I do that sometimes when I'm eating.

Comment: @teylyn `=SUM(A1+B1)` and `=A1+B1` are effectively the same and error out if A1 or B1 are not numbers.  `=SUM(A1,B1)` always produces an answer.

Comment: "(Yes, these people exist, and I don't know why they do that)" - I didn't know you could do calculations in the formula bar without typing out the formula you are using. Does it always work without it?

Comment: When I use an `&`, Excel seems to have a tendency to try to select the rest of the row.  So, I've always used `CONCATENATE` to avoid that...

Comment: I would be more likely to use Concatenate(a, b, c, d,...) rather than a & b & c & d ... because adding or removing terms from the list becomes less tedious by not having extra ampersands to deal with.  The difference in how long it takes to type "concatenate" and "& & & &" is totally negligible, and the word becomes significantly faster once there are more items.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian that's because you're still holding down the Shift key when you hit that spacebar.

Comment: @teylyn Is it like those people that like to type more and overuse parentheses because they understand operators, but not BODMAS? `=(A1*A2)-A3` may well be more concise (and more logical) than `=Sum((A1*A2)-A3)` but `=A1*A2-A3` is even more concise than `=(A1*A2)-A3` ;-)

Comment: @ThunderFrame True. Touche.

Comment: +1 for "It's for people who like to type more" alone. The rest is just (very good) icing.

Comment: @teylyn Maybe because they associate "sums" with performing calculations, so they're telling Excel "OK, I want you to work out this sum..."

Comment: -1. While the answer is funny, it is also pointless. The question was not "Why are people using CONCATENATE instead of &?" but "Why should one does CONCATENATE instead of &?". The answer is "it is completely equivalent, the Excel online help states that & should be used instead". The correct (and helpful) explanation, e.g. from Aganju, is that & came later and CONCATENATE has been left in for compatibility reasons, which is a completely valid reason. All this "people are stupid and want to type much" is completely uncalled-for; there *are* reasons why they do that and it's not their stupidity.

Comment: @DarrenRinger you have one less `&` but one more comma to type

Comment: @AnoE do you have a proof for `&` being later than `CONCATENATE`? if yes then you should post it as an answer

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, sorry, my memory failed me here; I now checked the old Excel 2.0 manuals. Excel 2.0 had `&` but not `CONCATENATE`. So I assume there *was* indeed a good reason why `CONCATENATE` was introduced later, probably to create compatibility with some other product that started out with `CONCATENATE`. I do not know (and don't want to read all manuals of Excel 3, 4, 5... ;) when `CONCATENATE` was added.

Comment: +1 for pointing out `TextJoin`. I can't believe it wasn't implemented earlier, but it took me an embarrassingly long time to discover that in 2016. It's so useful and pretty versatile I'm thankful to the Excel Gods/Devs for bringing it in.

Answer (score 21):

It's probably because they're using the Insert Function button.

[image]

I sometimes do this when I'm eating with my left hand and am just doing some low level formulas, or when I'm using a touch device and couldn't be bothered switching between the symbols, letters, and numbers on the touch screen.

Comment: +1   Yup. I've always used the button, it was sufficient, so there is no incentive to learn operators.

Comment: To concat strings I need to remember dot `.` for perl, pipe-pipe `||` for SQL, no char for cmd and bash, `+` for Java. Do I really need `&` just for Excel?

Comment: Even in the screenshot, I recently used this button for **sum()**!

Comment: @kubanczyk if you can remember those `.`, `||` and `+` then you can remember `&`. It's easier than `concatenate`, esp. if one isn't quite fluent at English. It's also used in VBA

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Re fluency in English - as far as I know, those function names are localized (e.g., it is `VERKETTEN`in German Excel)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen another good reason to use the operator over the function!

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc @kubanczyk Of course, `+` in VBA (depending upon the operand types) is different to `+` in Excel: `?"a"+"b" 'Prints ab` while `="a"+"b"` returns `#VALUE!`

Comment: On the other hand, I don't think I've _ever_ hit the `Insert function` button, I keep the ribbon minimized (it takes up _way_ too much screen real estate, even at 1920x1200), and I had to go rummaging about to figure out which menu holds that button. I'm kinda an old-school keyboard guy, though.

Answer (score 17):

It has only historical and compatibility reasons. Former versions of Excel didn't support one format, and other spreadsheet tools (like Google Docs, Apple Numbers, or Open Office) didn't support the other one.

Choose whichever you prefer.

Note that depending on your save format, Excel needs more space to save `CONCATENATE()` than `&`.

Comment: Yup.  I didn't know that `&` was the replacement for `CONCATENATE` until now.  I rarely use excel, but when I do it's usually for something which needs concatenation

Answer (score 15):

In my opinion, the selective use of concatenate *and* ampersands, can lead to clearer formulas.

This concatenation of address details, using a *mixture* of `CONCATENATE` and `&` seems clearer to me:

```
=CONCATENATE(StreetNumber," ",StreetName," ",StreetType) & CHAR(10) & CONCATENATE(CityName," ",StateCode," ",ZipCode) & CHAR(10) & CountryName
```

Than the *exclusive* use of `&`:

```
=StreetNumber & " " & StreetName & " " & StreetType & CHAR(10) & CityName & " " & StateCode & " " & ZipCode & CHAR(10) & CountryName
```

*And* the exclusive use of `CONCATENATE`

```
=CONCATENATE(StreetNumber," ",StreetName," ",StreetType,CHAR(10),CityName," ",StateCode," ",ZipCode,CHAR(10),CountryName)
```

Then again, I'd argue that a UDF like `BuildAddress` would be a better solution (and would be better placed to handle the subtleties of address formatting in internationalization domains - although I haven't implemented that)...

```vb
Public Function BuildAddress(ByVal StreetNumber As String, ByVal StreetName As String, _
    ByVal StreetType As String, ByVal CityName As String, ByVal StateCode As String, _
    ByVal ZipCode As String, ByVal CountryName As String) As String


    BuildAddress = StreetNumber & " " & StreetName & " " & StreetType & vbCrLf & _
                   CityName & " " & StateCode & " " & ZipCode & vbCrLf & _
                   CountryName

End Function
```

But perhaps another example, that includes the use of `&` *within* the string literal, better demonstrates the difficulty of reading a formula that forces itself to *exclusively* use operators:

```vb
=A1&"A2&A3&A4"&A5
```

Might be better written as:

```vb
=CONCATENATE(A1,"A2&A3&A4",A5)
```

But the *performance* is what matters, and depending upon the number of arguments being concatenated, and the length of each argument, the `CONCATENATE` function would appear to outperform the concatenation operator by a factor of between 4 and 6. Admittedly, this example is extreme, with 255 arguments being concatenated, 10,000 times. **I do not recommend using an argument string length greater than 32, or you may run out of memory/crash Excel.**

Here's a crude timing mechanism:

```vb
Option Explicit

Const ConcatenationOperatorFormula As String = _
  "=$A$1&$A$2&$A$3&$A$4&$A$5&$A$6&$A$7&$A$8&$A$9&$A$10&$A$11&$A$12&$A$13&$A$14&$A$15&$A$16&$A$17&$A$18&$A$19&$A$20&$A$21&$A$22&$A$23&$A$24&$A$25&$A$26&$A$27&$A$28&$A$29&$A$30&$A$31&$A$32&$A$33&$A$34&$A$35&$A$36&$A$37&$A$38&$A$39&$A$40&$A$41&$A$42&$A$43&$A$44&$A$45&$A$46&$A$47&$A$48&$A$49&$A$50&$A$51&$A$52&$A$53&$A$54&$A$55&$A$56&$A$57&$A$58&$A$59&$A$60&$A$61&$A$62&$A$63&$A$64&$A$65&$A$66&$A$67&$A$68&$A$69&$A$70&$A$71&$A$72&$A$73&$A$74&$A$75&$A$76&$A$77&$A$78&$A$79&$A$80&$A$81&$A$82&$A$83&$A$84&$A$85&$A$86&$A$87&$A$88&$A$89&$A$90&$A$91&$A$92&$A$93&$A$94&$A$95&$A$96&$A$97&$A$98&$A$99&$A$100&" & _
  "$A$101&$A$102&$A$103&$A$104&$A$105&$A$106&$A$107&$A$108&$A$109&$A$110&$A$111&$A$112&$A$113&$A$114&$A$115&$A$116&$A$117&$A$118&$A$119&$A$120&$A$121&$A$122&$A$123&$A$124&$A$125&$A$126&$A$127&$A$128&$A$129&$A$130&$A$131&$A$132&$A$133&$A$134&$A$135&$A$136&$A$137&$A$138&$A$139&$A$140&$A$141&$A$142&$A$143&$A$144&$A$145&$A$146&$A$147&$A$148&$A$149&$A$150&$A$151&$A$152&$A$153&$A$154&$A$155&$A$156&$A$157&$A$158&$A$159&$A$160&$A$161&$A$162&$A$163&$A$164&$A$165&$A$166&$A$167&$A$168&$A$169&$A$170&$A$171&$A$172&$A$173&$A$174&$A$175&$A$176&$A$177&$A$178&$A$179&$A$180&$A$181&$A$182&$A$183&$A$184&$A$185&$A$186&$A$187&$A$188&$A$189&$A$190&$A$191&$A$192&$A$193&$A$194&$A$195&$A$196&$A$197&$A$198&$A$199&$A$200&" & _
  "$A$201&$A$202&$A$203&$A$204&$A$205&$A$206&$A$207&$A$208&$A$209&$A$210&$A$211&$A$212&$A$213&$A$214&$A$215&$A$216&$A$217&$A$218&$A$219&$A$220&$A$221&$A$222&$A$223&$A$224&$A$225&$A$226&$A$227&$A$228&$A$229&$A$230&$A$231&$A$232&$A$233&$A$234&$A$235&$A$236&$A$237&$A$238&$A$239&$A$240&$A$241&$A$242&$A$243&$A$244&$A$245&$A$246&$A$247&$A$248&$A$249&$A$250&$A$251&$A$252&$A$253&$A$254&$A$255"

Const ConcatenateFunctionFormula As String = _
  "=CONCATENATE($A$1,$A$2,$A$3,$A$4,$A$5,$A$6,$A$7,$A$8,$A$9,$A$10,$A$11,$A$12,$A$13,$A$14,$A$15,$A$16,$A$17,$A$18,$A$19,$A$20,$A$21,$A$22,$A$23,$A$24,$A$25,$A$26,$A$27,$A$28,$A$29,$A$30,$A$31,$A$32,$A$33,$A$34,$A$35,$A$36,$A$37,$A$38,$A$39,$A$40,$A$41,$A$42,$A$43,$A$44,$A$45,$A$46,$A$47,$A$48,$A$49,$A$50,$A$51,$A$52,$A$53,$A$54,$A$55,$A$56,$A$57,$A$58,$A$59,$A$60,$A$61,$A$62,$A$63,$A$64,$A$65,$A$66,$A$67,$A$68,$A$69,$A$70,$A$71,$A$72,$A$73,$A$74,$A$75,$A$76,$A$77,$A$78,$A$79,$A$80,$A$81,$A$82,$A$83,$A$84,$A$85,$A$86,$A$87,$A$88,$A$89,$A$90,$A$91,$A$92,$A$93,$A$94,$A$95,$A$96,$A$97,$A$98,$A$99,$A$100," & _
  "$A$101,$A$102,$A$103,$A$104,$A$105,$A$106,$A$107,$A$108,$A$109,$A$110,$A$111,$A$112,$A$113,$A$114,$A$115,$A$116,$A$117,$A$118,$A$119,$A$120,$A$121,$A$122,$A$123,$A$124,$A$125,$A$126,$A$127,$A$128,$A$129,$A$130,$A$131,$A$132,$A$133,$A$134,$A$135,$A$136,$A$137,$A$138,$A$139,$A$140,$A$141,$A$142,$A$143,$A$144,$A$145,$A$146,$A$147,$A$148,$A$149,$A$150,$A$151,$A$152,$A$153,$A$154,$A$155,$A$156,$A$157,$A$158,$A$159,$A$160,$A$161,$A$162,$A$163,$A$164,$A$165,$A$166,$A$167,$A$168,$A$169,$A$170,$A$171,$A$172,$A$173,$A$174,$A$175,$A$176,$A$177,$A$178,$A$179,$A$180,$A$181,$A$182,$A$183,$A$184,$A$185,$A$186,$A$187,$A$188,$A$189,$A$190,$A$191,$A$192,$A$193,$A$194,$A$195,$A$196,$A$197,$A$198,$A$199,$A$200," & _
  "$A$201,$A$202,$A$203,$A$204,$A$205,$A$206,$A$207,$A$208,$A$209,$A$210,$A$211,$A$212,$A$213,$A$214,$A$215,$A$216,$A$217,$A$218,$A$219,$A$220,$A$221,$A$222,$A$223,$A$224,$A$225,$A$226,$A$227,$A$228,$A$229,$A$230,$A$231,$A$232,$A$233,$A$234,$A$235,$A$236,$A$237,$A$238,$A$239,$A$240,$A$241,$A$242,$A$243,$A$244,$A$245,$A$246,$A$247,$A$248,$A$249,$A$250,$A$251,$A$252,$A$253,$A$254,$A$255)"

Const ARGUMENT_STRING_LENGTH As Long = 1

Sub test2()

  Dim start As Single

  'Disable app events to exclude UI/calculation artefacts
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  Dim inputs As Range
  Set inputs = Range("A1:A255")

  Dim operatorRange As Range
  Set operatorRange = Range("B1:B10000")

  Dim functionRange As Range
  Set functionRange = Range("C1:C10000")

  'Reset the range values/formulas
  inputs.Value2 = ""
  operatorRange.Formula = ConcatenationOperatorFormula
  functionRange.Formula = ConcatenateFunctionFormula

  'Change the inputs to invalidate the calculation results
  inputs.Value2 = String(ARGUMENT_STRING_LENGTH, "B")

  'Time the calculation of operator formulas
  start = Timer
  operatorRange.Calculate
  Debug.Print "Operator Calculation", ARGUMENT_STRING_LENGTH, FormatNumber(Timer - start, 8)

  'Time the calculation of function formulas
  start = Timer
  functionRange.Calculate
  Debug.Print "Function Calculation", ARGUMENT_STRING_LENGTH, FormatNumber(Timer - start, 8)

  'Reset the range values to empty
  inputs.Value2 = ""
  operatorRange.Value2 = vbNullString
  functionRange.Value2 = vbNullString

  'Restore App defaults
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

And the results, according to the length of the argument strings:

```vb
Method                 String Length   Seconds
---------------------  --------------  -----------
Function Calculation   1               0.06640625
Operator Calculation   1               0.21484380
Function Calculation   10              0.09765625
Operator Calculation   10              0.47265630
Function Calculation   32              0.17578130
Operator Calculation   32              1.17968800
```

But then, we haven't even discussed the elephant in the room. **You're building a SQL command using concatenation. Don't do that.** You're executing a stored procedure that accepts parameters. Unless you've sanitized your inputs (and I'm guessing you haven't), building a SQL string using concatenation is asking for a SQL-injection attack. You might as well expose a UDF called `JohnnyDropTables`...

Comment: You are making a healthy amount of assumptions on that last part....

Answer (score 5):

It is a semantic domain difference.  Concatenate is the name of a spreadsheet function. The Ampersand is a concatenation **operator** borrowed from Visual Basic.  Folks who never open use VBA would find a function much easier to use than VBA Syntax.  It's the same reason why there is a hot-key, an icon, and a menu option to save, which is making software easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

I use both.

For long lists which I might need to review visually, a comma takes up less eye-space than an ampersand.

It's easier to read a list of cells separated by commas than separated by ampersands, especially since an ampersand looks (after a 15 hour day) too much like a $.

This provides a meaningful role for CONCATENATE.

But -- agree -- there's no speed benefit, or any functional difference.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the true answers in here, but do have some insight. (for anyone that may in future look up this answer)

"Concatenate" is an older legacy function, which does do the same things as the "&", "&" was added later on for consistency in programming languages.
However, "Concatenate" has been replaced by "Concat" to support ranges, so you can combine A1:A10 without needing any custom scripting. The "&" still does not allow a range and only takes the first cell in the same way "Concatenate" functions. So if combining a range, the "Concat" gives that extra function change over the previous 2 styles that are just coded differently. Making "Concatenate" and "&" essentially a preference when using non-range required combined strings on how you like to type it out.

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add that CONCATENATE/CONCAT can accept an array range of cells.
In the snip, a unique item number is being created simply by CONCAT(cellRange). It's faster than typing =A1&B1&C1....

[Use range arguments with CONCAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFWUA.png)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>One particular use case is that `=CONCATENATE(A1:A10)` is a lot shorter than `=A1&A2&A3&A4&A4&A6&A7&A8&A9&A10`.  It is also much more obviously correct (in fact the example `&` version has a deliberate mistake).</strike>

I tried this first, but I was using the office Excel, which is in German.  `TEXTKETTE` behaves as I describe, but the documentation shows it is a newish function, and replaces `VERKETTEN` (which will be the German equivalent of `CONCATENATE`).

Comment: @Vylix: No, I mean that the `CONCATENATE` form is more obviously correct.  If you want to concatenate all the elements of a range, giving the range is much *less* error-prone, than giving each element one by one.

Comment: The specific example of the `&` form has a deliberate mistake.

Comment: @MartinBonner `=CONCATENATE(A1:A10)`  does not work in Excel.  If you have such a function, it's a custom UDF, not native Excel. But it can't be a UDF with the same name as the native function.

Comment: @MartinBonner Your argument might hold for a function like `SUM` and operators like `+`, but it does not apply to Excel's `CONCATENATE` function. `=CONCATENATE(A1:A2)` is **never** the same result as `=A1&A2`

Comment: `=CONCATENATE(A1:A10)` gives the result of `A1`, so it's obviously not only shorter but different

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc #ItDepends  - If your formula in cell `B1` is `=CONCATENATE(A1:A10)`, the result is the value in `A1`, but if the same formula is in `B2`, the result is the value in `A2`. If the same formula is in `B11`, then the result is `#VALUE!`

Comment: The function you really meant is called CONCAT() in Excel. Just like TextJoin(), which is TEXTVERKETTEN() in German, this function is only available in Excel 2016 on a 365 subscription license.

Answer (score -6):

[RTFM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) Microsoft says use the `&`.

BTW, you will get different answers when using the SUM operator.

[image]

Comment: "CONCATENATE may not be available in future versions of Excel." Haha, right. They still support `=` alternatives - entering functions like `@CONCATENATE(A1,A2)` and calculations like `+A5+A6` or `-A5+A6`.

Comment: "Read The F'n Manual" isn't exactly what [be nice](https://superuser.com/help/be-nice) is about.

Comment: @Mat'sMug The F can also stand for Fine :)